# Elasticsearch - Wildcard vs Prefix vs vs Regexp vs query_string differences and performance

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, tags, full-text-search

I've just started using Elasticsearch for my project and I want to search like the sql keyword **'like%'** does.

1. Could anyone please explain what are the differences between **Wildcard**, **Prefix**, **query_string** and **Regexp**?
2. Which one can search with the best **performance**?
3. Is it the best way to search rapidly between product tags with defining the **keyword** field and search with one of the three ways which I mentioned?

I appreciate whoever answers me.

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask you what is your use-case exactly? Do you need a kind of autocomplete behavior, to, let's say, suggest users the product names as they type?

Comment: Dear @NikolayVasiliev, Yes exactly I want autocomplete for showing tags while user is typing.

Answer (score 7):

#### Which query is better?

Let me answer point by point.

> 1. Could anyone please explain what are the differences between Wildcard, Prefix, query_string and Regexp?

They are very similar in what they can do and how they are implemented. In fact, [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html), [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), and [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) [are equally bad in performance](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/prefix-vs-wildcard-vs-regexp-in-terms-of-performance-and-usability/98460). [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query allows for a more complex queries, for instance using logical operators like `OR` and `AND`. `query_string` supports [wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards), which I believe are the same wildcards as `wildcard` query does.

> 2. Which one can search with the best performance?

Bottomline: they all are bad.

> 3. Is it the best way to search rapidly between product tags with defining the keyword field and search with one of the three ways which I mentioned?

I believe that if you use a [boolean filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query to reduce amount of matched documents then performance should improve, but the performance gain might still be overwhelmed with how inefficient regexp-like queries from above are.

#### How can I implement autocomplete with Elasticsearch?

As you mentioned in the comment above, you would like to implement an autocomplete, so the [`search_as_you_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-as-you-type.html) data type might be exactly what you are looking for.

Another similar feature is [suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-suggesters.html). Both of them will try to use a more efficient term-based matching, and not regexp-based.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, with your motivation I finally used **search_as_you_type** but what is the most efficient way for search like '%foo%' ? Is it the right way? **query_string' =>["default_field"=>"title",'query'=>'*'.$Title.'*']**

Comment: @Arash.Zandi Glad that you found something useful for you! About your question, I am not sure I understand what you mean with dots in the `query` part. If you mean wildcards, then they have [different syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) and they are as efficient as regexes and such (as said in the answer above).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance dear @Nikolay